# Force SSLv3 connection on MacOS / IOS SDK

Tags: ios, macos, ssl

Is there a way to force and/or check which version of SSL your system negotiated on an NSURLRequest? I've been trying to figure this out all morning.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to drop down to `CFNetwork` and set the `kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelSSLv3` property on your stream.